# How to send an array of objects to a WCF service?

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, service

I am trying to pass the following to call of WCF service function, but it doesn't receive it.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Sheet
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SheetName {get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Row[] RowList { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Row
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string[] ColumnValues { get; set; }
    }

public ResultData CreateExcel(out string fileName, string prefixName2, Sheet[] sheetList) 
{...}
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that arrays are cause of your trouble. Try from simple prototype code and step by step add your logic.
Could you specify details:

1. Which kind of errors you were received?
2. What does CreateExcel method in your code?

Check out next article - [Collection Types in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Possible that helps you.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. I will read the stuff in the link. I am getting error null reference exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  at DocWcfService.Excel.AddSheet(Workbook workbook, Sheet sheet, Int32 sheetIndex). In the CreateExcel function I am creating excel file and i want to walk through the collection of sheets but it is null.

Comment: @Diana I just created simple WCF app, added 'string[] ColumnValues' like in your code and run my app in WCF test client. It works. Now about your excel code - looks like problem there. Try to specify (maybe in separate theme) details - how you are creating excel file and where do you take sheets so on.